# How do i make sure that the contents are centered when zooming out/in

Tags: html, css

Can someone give a brief explanation on how i could make sure that the contents of my web page stay centered when zoomed out or in . For example,
https://rocketman.learnwagtail.com/
when you zoom out on this dummy website the contents stay in the center and the margin adjusts itself automatically.

please can someone explain this to me with some examples and also refer some videos to understand this even better .

thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
```